# Flutter - Can Google Sign in be used without firebase?

Tags: firebase, authentication, flutter, dart

There [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) package on pub.dev, bu the link it provides for setting the application up points to https://firebase.google.com/?platform=android...

Thanks!

Comment: refer this link https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-sign-in-with-google-in-android-without-firebase-a91b977d166f

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes ! you can.

1. Create project in cloud console.
2. Create OAuth 2.0 clientId (by restricting it with package name)
3. Download the JSON and place it in android->app folder, thats it.
4. Procced the steps as in google_sign_in package without getting into firebase

   ```
    GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
      clientId:"xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com");
   ```

clientId is optional- but required in flutter web

Also refer this for [flutter web google sign in without firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52DM6y4lFaQ)

Comment: what about google sign in on apple devices

Comment: Does this work well on iOS??

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Try visa  - https://github.com/e-oj/visa

Here's an example with Facebook auth (It also supports google, twitch, discord, and Github):

```dart
import 'package:visa/auth-data.dart';
import 'package:visa/fb.dart';

class AuthPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      /// Simply Provide all the necessary credentials
      body: FaceBookAuth().visa.authenticate(
          clientID: '139732240983759',
          redirectUri: 'https://www.e-oj.com/oauth',
          scope: 'public_profile,email',
          state: 'fbAuth',
          onDone: done
      )
    );
  }
}
```

and the "done" callback:

```dart
done(AuthData authData){
  print(authData);

  /// You can pass the [AuthData] object to a 
  /// post-authentication screen. It contaions 
  /// all the user and OAuth data collected during
  /// the authentication process. In this example,
  /// our post-authentication screen is "complete-profile".
  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
      context, '/complete-profile', arguments: authData
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have completed the OAuth 2.0 clientid steps above, your google login button may not work after it is published on platforms such as google play. For this, enter your Google cloud account and create another package name and signing key region from the OAuth clientid section. then paste the signing key that google play gave you there (SHA-1). It will be working in a few hours

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgpII.png)