# Flutter authentication with email and password without using Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, cookies

Is it possible to achive authentication with email and password in flutter without using firebase? I have searched around Stackoverflow and internet in general and found nothing about this.
I am creating a simple authentication class this is what I have done at the moment:

```
class User {
  bool isAuthenticated = false;
  late String userid;
  late String username;
  late String email;
  late DateTime expireDate; // this variable is used to make the user re-authenticate when today is expireDate

  User(bool isAuthenticated, String userid, String username, String email) {
    this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
    this.userid = userid;
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.expireDate = new DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: 30));
  }
}

class Authentication {
  Future<User> signin(String email, String password) {}

  void signup(String username, String email, String password) {}
}
```

EDIT #1: I know how to setup a cookie/token based authentication server I have my own repos on that topic: [cookie authentication](https://github.com/datteroandrea/cookieauth), [token authentication](https://github.com/datteroandrea/jwtauth) but I don't know how to handle the tokens/cookies in flutter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57531535/flutter-can-google-sign-in-be-used-without-firebase did it resolve?

Comment: @Muhtar no in that question it is explained how to achieve google authentication with firebase, I would like to have email and password authentication without firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based of #edit1. Since you mentioned that you already know how to set up tokens on the server side you're half way done. Here's a few assumptions I'm making, you already know js/php and worked with JSON output, The database already has a column and table that keeps track of sessions and user_id.

Since you know how Cookies are built this should be relatively easy cause i built it around similar architecture. We has to use the local memory that app's provide access to. There are two packages in flutter that allow u to do this, you can use either:

- shared_preferences [package link](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)
- flutter_secure_storage [package link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage)

The main difference is if you want to store 'tokens' or data you want secure you would obviously use flutter_secure_storage. I'm going to use this for code example. And yes the data is saved even after the app is closed.

### Setting up Tokens(flutter):

1. Setting up User Class

When using firebase we generally take for granted the user class that comes with flutter_auth but that is basically what we have to build. A user class with all the data u want to store and then a function called authenticate.

```
 class AppUser{
     final _storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
     //below class is mentioned in the next part 
     AuthApi api = new AuthApi();

     //constructor 
     AppUser(){
         //ur data; 
     }; 

     Future<bool> authenticate(email, password) async {
         //this is the api mentioned in next part 
         http.Response res = await api.login(email, password);
         Map<String, dynamic> jsonRes = jsonDecode(res.body);

         if (jsonRes["error"]) {
              return false;
         }
         _setToken(jsonRes["token"]);
         _setUID(jsonRes["user-id"].toString());
         _setAuthState(true); 
         return true; 
     }

     Future<void> _setToken(String val) async {
         //how to write to safe_storage 
         await _storage.write(key: 'token', value: val);
     }
     Future<void> _setUID(String val) async {
         await _storage.write(key: 'user_id', value: val);
     }

      //you can stream this or use it in a wrapper to help navigate 
      Future<bool> isAuthenticated() async {
         bool authState = await _getAuthState();
         return authState;
      }

      Future<void> _getAuthState() async {
         //how to read from safe_storage u can use the same to read token later just replace 'state' with 'token'
         String myState = (await _storage.read(key: 'state')).toString();
         //returns boolean true or false 
         return myState.toLowerCase() == 'true';
      } 

      Future<void> _setAuthState(bool liveAuthState) async {
         await _storage.write(key: 'state', value: liveAuthState.toString());
      }

 }
```

and assuming ur going to authenticate on a button press so it would look like

```
onPressed(){
        AuthUser user = new AuthUser(); 
        if(user.authenticate(email, password)){
            //if logged in. Prolly call Navigator.
        }else{
            //handle error
        }
}
```

2. Setting up api calls

Oka so this is calling a Node express API, and the json output looks like

```
//if successful 
{"status":200, "error": false, "token": "sha256token", "user-id": "uid"}
```

we need to create a class that will give us an output for making this call hence the AuthApi class

```
class AuthApi {
   //this is the login api and it returns the above JSON 
   Future<http.Response> login(String email, String password){
        return http.post(
           Uri.parse(ip + '/api/auth/login'),
           headers: <String, String>{
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           },
           body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
           "email": email,
           "password": password,
           }),
       );
  }
}
```

Thank you for clarifying what u needed, it helped answer better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nodejs & express to create your own API and MongoDB or any other DB to act as a persistent DB. I am attaching my github repo link which has minimum code required to setup a email/password auth in mongodb

[Github](https://github.com/AshutoshPatole/backends)
EDIT :

I have little to no idea about sessions but for tokens there are packages in pub.dev which lets you decode the tokens. [jwt-decoder](https://pub.dev/packages/jwt_decoder).
You can check the expiry time of the token using this package and for storing them you can use [secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage)

I had a look at your token authentication repo. I would suggest you to verify the token when you get them and not just blindly trust them.

Comment: This is not a valid answer I alredy know how to setup a backend server with authentication I have my own repos: [token authentication](https://github.com/datteroandrea/jwtauth) and [cookie authentication](https://github.com/datteroandrea/cookieauth), my problem is how to handle the cookie/tokens in flutter.

Comment: @AndreaDattero You should have mentioned it in your question first.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is Totally possible to create Authentication without Firebase, but it becomes a-lot more difficult and there are multiple solutions.

### What firebase provides:

1. Server space with no down time
2. Complete set of Api's including authentication with various methods
3. Strong security(built by google)
4. Ease of use and setup with great documentation

The reason I bring these up is cause the alternative ur looking for is very difficult for a programer who's relatively new and can feel like you are building multiple applications at a time. It's definitely a learning curve. Also I'm assuming u don't just want local authentication cause thats kinda pointless.

### Creating ur own backend involves:

1. Setting up a server(usually ubuntu)(and either on a raspi or a host like amazon, digital ocean, etc)
2. Setting up a database with tables(mysql, sql, mongoDB)
3. Creating communication API's (php, Node.js)

So here's what i'd recommend for getting into backend dev,
use LAMP architecture : Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP

Setting up Lamp isn't too hard heres a link i followed:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

After u set up ur back end, then u have to create api calls from flutter.
The call (if u created an auth.php where people can login) would look something like:

```
http://ip:8080/auth.php?email="example@gmail.com"&pass="123456"
```

I understand why you feel like you didn't find solutions, i was there too but there are tons,LAMP is one of the more easier ones. If u are still interested i'd recommend checking out System Design courses.

Comment: This is not a valid answer I alredy know how to setup a backend server with authentication I have my own repos: [https://github.com/datteroandrea/jwtauth](token authentication) and [https://github.com/datteroandrea/cookieauth](cookie authentication), my problem is how to handle the cookie/tokens in flutter.

Comment: oh if you were a bit more specific i could've answerd better, i just created a project with sessions. if you read ur question again it didnt mention it.. i will add it now

Comment: This answer basically ignores the part in questions which says "without using Firebase"

Comment: @000 the initial question didnt mention anything about cookies or token handling. The question was can you have authentication without firebase, to which i mentioned clearly about setting up your own backend server...